# Moving AWS RDS database to local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Can anybody tell me how to copy my AWS RDS database to my local development machine? Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Which database engine are you using (eg MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle)?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL. I have tried logging into the server through my local psql but to no avail.

Comment: Found this: [Exporting data from an RDS for PostgreSQL DB instance to Amazon S3 - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/postgresql-s3-export.html)

Comment: How many tables, how much data? Sometimes it is just simplest to use `pg_dump` to extract from PostgreSQL and then load it into the target database using `psql`. If you cannot login to the RDS database using `psql`, then try to get that working first. You should check the Security Group on the database, and whether it is Publicly Accessible.